# Is it possible to create a trigger which is triggered on any insert in any table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I would like to create a MySQL trigger which runs before any row insert in any table. Is that possible? The alternative is to create a trigger before insert for each table, but that is not good enough: it is messy and it doesn't handle new tables, so I would definitely like to write a MySQL trigger which is triggered on any insert into any row. Is that possible? If so, how? (I could not find any reference to that in the documentation)

Comment: short answer is yes. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145185/how-to-write-mysql-trigger

Comment: @user2065377, the linked question's answers are solving this problem? How? I want the trigger to be triggered on any insert into any table.

Comment: I do mot believe it's possible or advisable.  Unless it's your private database that you use once and then discard, such database-wise action will come to bite you at some point.

Comment: @Twelfth, I want to find some dependies, CFDs and ARs and then generate constraints for those. There is no problem in generating the constraints (I generate a MySQL procedure in my Java code), but I would like to apply those constraints so if any insert or update breaks any rules an error is raised. To simplify matters I was asking only about inserts in this question. But the generated constraints will only be useful if insertion which breaks the rule is prevented.

Comment: @PM77-1, I would like to achieve the same mechanism with CFDs and ARs as with foreign keys. This is not supported in the current moment in MySQL, so I would like to work around it.

Comment: @Lajos sorry, I deleted my comment there.   my question for others was 'what are you trying to accomplish'.   It seems very generic to do it at this level and too be honest, might end up biting you in the @$$ down the road.  Have you considered using a storedproc for inserts (lock your tables from inserts and only allow inserts from stored procedures) and have that stored proc 'trigger' whatever code you need here?

Comment: if you want a specific answer, please provide a specific question. I might be out of line her, sorry. The link gives an example of how-to-write-mysql-trigger.

Comment: @user2065377  read the question again, you linked to 'how to create a table trigger' when the question was how to trigger on all inserts not just a single table.

Comment: This is a pretty good question. You should add a bounty for it

Comment: I am considering to give a bounty for it.  Twelfth, a database can be used by multiple applications. If I call the stored procedure by an application when I insert anything with that, then what guarantees that the other application will also call the stored procedure? Not to mention the fact that queries can be issued directly on the database without applications. So, using a stored procedure to apply my constraints only provides the illusion of a constraint, nothing more. My problem is database-scheme agnostic and it is solvable in Oracle, for instance as far as I know.

Comment: You are right with Oracle...triggers can reside on schema's and databases as readily as they can on a table, while MySQL seems relatively mild in what it's triggers can accomplish.  Sorry Lajos, from my research the only thing I can find here is work arounds like using a stored proc or the sort so users are no longer directly accessing the tables.  I'd be curious if you find an answer

Answer (score 0):

Go for a instead of trigger 
ex: in sql server

```
create trigger name
on table_name
instead of insert 
as
begin
if exists9select count(*) from inserted as i
join table_name as t
on i.id-t.id
group by i.id
having count(*) >1)
begin
raiseerror "duplicate category names npt allowsed"
end
else
insert into table_name (col1,col2)
select col1,col2 from inserted

`create trigger name
on table_name
instead of insert 
as
begin
if exists9select count(*) from inserted as i
join table_name as t
on i.id-t.id
group by i.id
having count(*) >1)
begin
raise error "duplicate category names not allowed"
end
else
insert into table_name (col1,col2)
select col1,col2 from inserted
end
go
```

`

Comment: The question is clearly about MySQL and even if it was SQL Server, the answer would not tackle the question asked (which asks for an insert trigger that works "independently" of any table)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, I have asked the guys from MySQL and they assured me that MySQL does not support currently this feature and it is not even planned for anytime soon, so nope, no hope at all, that's the answer.